# Image of bilinear map is union of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If $U,V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over the field $K$, and $f:U\times V\to W$ is a bilinear map, then how to do we show that the image of $f$ is a union of subspaces of $W$?

Comment: Did you attempt to solve it on yourself? Could you provide some context, thoughts or at least some work?

Comment: I can show that f(u*v)= f(u*{0}) U f({0}*v), but i do not know if that proves what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A set $S\subseteq W$ is union of vector subspaces if and only if $\lambda s\in S$ for all $\lambda\in k$ and for all $s\in S$. I leave it to you to check why this is the case for $\operatorname{im}f$, and perhaps why the previous consideration holds.

Comment: Why is it that a set is union of subspaces iff lamda(s) belongs to s?

Comment: if and only if $\lambda s\in S$ **for all** $\lambda\in k$ **and for all** $s\in S$. In symbols $$\iff \forall \lambda\in k,\forall s\in S,\ \lambda s\in S$$

Comment: Is there a theorem that says that?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a *theorem*. Moreso a lemma that I made up a few minutes ago.

Comment: Can you explain why that lemma is true?

Comment: I won't go back on leaving it as an exercise for the reader.